# Unable to register Oracle performance counters

Tags: oracle, odp.net, performancecounter

I am using Oracle Managed Data Access NuGet package (Oracle.ManagedDataAccess) and would like to enable Oracle performance counters. They are not displayed Performance Monitor and I found an article suggesting how to manually register them:
http://blog.bekijkhet.com/2010/01/odpnet-performance-counters-do-not-show.html

I've followed the article, downloaded OraProvCfg from Oracle Web site (it was a part of the ODP.NET package), now I am trying to run the following command:

> OraProvCfg /action:register /product:odp /component:perfcounter
>   /providerpath:C:\ODP.NET\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess\lib\net40\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll

However, it displays the error:

**ERROR: Unable to find the type :.OraclePerfCounterConfiguration or .OraclePerfCollection.**

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to turn on performance counters via an entry in your apps web.config or app.config. For example: <oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
        <version number="*">
          <settings>
            <setting name="PerformanceCounters" value="4095"/>
          </settings>
        </version></oracle.manageddataaccess.client>Also, you cannot see the performance counters unless your application is running first. Run the app, then start perfmon.

Comment: @ChristianShay's comment that the application has to be run first also applies to ASP.Net web applications, and to using logman to create/start a log.  Logman will let you create and start a data collector set referencing the ODP.Net performance counters, but the logfiles will have no values (or even appropriate column headers) unless you run the application BEFORE starting the DCS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The product needs to be odpm

OraProvCfg /action:register /product:**odpm** /component:perfcounter /providerpath:C:\ODP.NET\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess\lib\net40\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll

And you need to run the command as an **admin**.

Comment: This is correct and we plan to update the Performance Counters section in the documentation to make this more clear. Note, that of this writing, if you are using Nuget, you will have to install another ODAC package to obtain OraProvCfg.exe